# Find key that contains certain characters in a hashtable with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashtable

I have a hash that's something like this:

```
hash = { "key1-one" => 3, "key1-two" => 6, "key2-one" => 5, "key2-two" => 9 }
```

Now I want to find values with keys starting with `key1`, regardless of what follows. I've tried `has_key?` but it doesn't seem to work. I know I can use regex but is there already a built-in method for Ruby?

Comment: Are these keys Strings or Symbols?

Comment: hey Maxim, they're strings

Comment: You can do soemthing like this `hash.map {|k, v| v if k.start_with?("key1")} `

Comment: Hey @nmeylan that worked a charm. Thanks for that. I overlooked `start_with?`

Comment: nmeylan solution is good one just add compact in the end hash.map {|k, v| v if k.start_with?("key1")}.compact

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.select{ |key, _| key.start_with?("key1") }.values
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `hash` would be look like this:

```
hash = { "key1-one"=>3, :"key1-two"=>6, "key2-one"=>5, "key2-two"=> 9 }
```

And try this:

```
hash.select { |k, _v| k.to_s.include? "key1" }.values
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a new hash to extract the desired values:

```
hash.values_at *hash.keys.select { |k| k.start_with? 'key1' }
  #=> [3, 6]
```

The could of course use a regex in the block instead:

```
{ |k| k =~ /^key1/ }
```